# Bluetooth/BlueZ - 'rfcomm listen' command does not terminate

Tags: linux, bluetooth, lock, bluez

I have an issue with rfcomm command
- after invoking `rfcomm listen 0 1`
I have got (correctly) `Waiting for connection on channel 1`.
Then, I am connecting to a device via Android's application
Serial Bluetooth Terminal and (correctly) receive and send messages.
`Connection from FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF to /dev/rfcomm0` The problem arises when I am disconnecting the phone from the device. Even after a few minutes, the rfcomm command does not terminate. I have tested it in another terminal, 
with results:

command:

`rfcomm`

result:

`rfcomm0: 00:00:00:00:00:00 -> FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF channel 1 closed [reuse-dlc release-on-hup tty-attached]`

command:

`fuser rfcomm0`

result:

`/dev/rfcomm0:          675`

command:

`dev# ps -aef | grep '675'`

result:

`root       675   649  0 07:36 pts/1    00:00:00 rfcomm listen 0 1
root       694   628  0 07:50 pts/0    00:00:00 grep 675`

My OS version is Yocto 2.5

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue on Raspberry. I think it's bug in rfcomm utility.
Accidentally, I found a workaroud:

```
sudo rfcomm watch hci0 -L 86400
```

The arguments go a bit wrong way in the command above (-L 86400 must go first). It produces a small error inside of rfcomm, but hocus-pocus! If I now close the connection on the Android side the rfcomm server also terminates. That's a miracle:)

Comment: Thanks, chased this down for hours. I'm using it with direwolf TNC and without the -L option, I can't reconnect after disconnecting without restarting rfcomm manually.